# I'm trying to declare variables in sass but I can't because it's going wrong

Tags: html, css, sass

```
$bg-color: #ccc

body
background-color: $bg-color
```

Warning on line 5, column 5 of sass\estilo.sass:
This selector doesn't have any properties and won't be rendered.
╷
5 │     background-color: $bg-color
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵

Error: Expected identifier.
╷
5 │     background-color: $bg-color
│                      ^

Help me pleesee!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$bg-color: #ccc;

body {
  background-color: $bg-color;
}
```

Comment: Error: semicolons aren't allowed in the indented syntax.
  ╷
4 │     $bg-color: #ccc;
  │                    ^
  ╵
  sass\estilo.sass 4:20  root stylesheet